# wrap first few words of a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string and I need to wrap in span first few words from this strings, the number of these first words always be different. I can get the substring of first few words, but can't wrap it in span. How can I wrap every substring in every string?

```js
$('.title-js').each(function(){
    var titleText = $(this).text().trim();
    var $wordLength = parseInt($.trim($(this).text()).split(' ').length);
    var half = $wordLength/2;
    var halfString = titleText.split(' ').slice(0,half).join(' ');

    $(halfString).wrap("<span class = 'golden-words'></span>"); //here is a problem

    $(this).html(function(_,txt) {
        return txt.replace(/(.$)/, "<span class = 'golden-words'>$1</span>");
    });

});
```

```css
.golden-words {
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "title title-js">Some text part first.</div>
<div class = "title title-js">Some text part second!</div>
<div class = "title title-js">Some text part third?</div>
<div class = "title title-js">Some text part fourth)</div>
```

Comment: What error message you are getting

Comment: @JijoCleetus no error, console is clear

Comment: `jquery` is not `jq`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never assigned the contents of the element to `halfString`, nor combined it with the other half of the contents. The `txt.replace`regex only matches one character (`.`) and the end of the string (`$`).

This should work:

```js
$('.title-js').each(function(){
    var parts = $.trim($(this).text()).split(' ');
    
    var half = parts.length / 2;
    var firstHalf = parts.slice(0,half).join(' ');
    var secondHalf = parts.slice(half).join(' ');

    $(this).html("<span class = 'golden-words'>"+firstHalf+"</span> " + secondHalf);


});
```

```css
.golden-words {
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "title title-js">Some text part first.</div>
<div class = "title title-js">Some text part second!</div>
<div class = "title title-js">Some text part third?</div>
<div class = "title title-js">Some text part fourth)</div>
```